# How to print list with proper indentation in a file?

Tags: python

so i have this project that I should make a program to add identify or delete data from an inventory.txt file
but when I ever try to print the inputs in the file I get messy text, what I'm looking for is a table-like structure printed inputs in the .txt file, I've tried to remove and readjust the place of \n and \t but still, I get stuff like this in the file

Samsung ide445  2154SS  rams    120.0   14
Logetech    Specture    lid224  G502    230.0   8

here's my code for a closer look:

```
#This function is to get the parts information from the user
def input_parts():
    #Taking the parts input from the user
    try:
        make = input("Enter the make: ")
        model = input("Enter the model: ")
        part_id = input("Enter part_id: ")
        part_name = input("Enter part name: ")
        price = float(input("Enter price:QR "))
        quantity = int(input("Enter quantity: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("BOTH PRICE AND QUANTITY CAN NOT BE LETTERS, PLEASE RE-ENTER THE RIGHT DATA")
    else:
        #transferring both price and quantitiy to strings
        price = str(price)
        quantity = str(quantity)
        list = ['\n'+make,model,part_id,part_name,price,quantity]
        return list


#This function is to save the parts information to a file
def add_parts():
    #Assignning this sentinal to make the loop repeat if the user didn't want to save
    sentinal = True
    while sentinal is True:
        #Assigning the values of the inputs function to a variable
        parts = input_parts()
        #Validating user's unput
        try:
            #Asking the user if he wants to save the information to the file
            save = input("Save? (Y/N) or Q to quit ")
        except TypeError:
            print("YOU CANNOT SAVE WRONG DATA IN THE FILE PLEASE RE-ENTER YOUR DATA")
        else:
            pass
        #A boleen function to export the data to the file if the boleen is true
        if save.lower() == 'y':
            outfile = open('inventory.txt',"a")
            #Validating user's input
            try:
                #Using a for loop to print the information in the file
                for i in parts:
                    outfile.write(i+'\t')
            except TypeError:
                print("YOU CAN NOT SAVE WRONG DATA FILES!!!")
                break
            else:
                pass
            outfile.close
            print("....Record saved.")
            sentinal = False
        #Using an elif statment to enable the user to re input his data
        elif save.lower() == 'n':
            sentinal = True
        #Using an elif statment to quit if the user wants to
        elif save.lower() == 'q':
            break
        #Using else statment to tell the user no input a valid choice
        else:
            print("PLEASE ENTER (Y/N) IF YOU WANT TO SAVE!!!!")
            print("YOUR DATA HAS NOT BEEN SAVED")
            print("PLEASE RE-ENTER YOUR DATA AND TRY AGAIN.")
            sentinal = True


add_parts()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import `tabulate` module and use it as below example:

```
from tabulate import tabulate
print(tabulate([['Saeed', 26], ['You', 24]], headers=['Name', 'Age']))
```

Result:

```
Name      Age
------  -----
Saeed      26
You        24
```

You may use this module to reach what you want.